# How can I make my instant apps part of the app discovery experience such as launchers in Android O?

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

At Google IO 2017, there was a demo of searching for an app name in the launcher and launching an instant app. How can my instant app be part of the launcher?

Comment: If anyone else is curious, this is the video of the  https://youtu.be/3GpLV9xSDTQ?t=1m28s  
However, it doesn't seem to be available on any current **public O builds** from **Google**.

Answer (score 6):

You must specify a `meta-data` `default-url` for one activity in the instant app's [base feature](https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/getting-started/structure.html). This default-url will be used for launching the instant app from app discovery experiences such as from launchers in Android O.

Further, this default url must also be part of the [launcher](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#CATEGORY_LAUNCHER) activity's intent filter in the 'installed' app.

Example:

```
<activity android:label="@string/home_activity" 
   android:name="com.myApp.HomeActivity">
      <meta-data android:name="default-url" android:value="https://www.myapp.com”>
</activity>
```